# subdomain to directory redirect in litespeed webserver

Tags: wordpress, redirect, litespeed

searched a lot but can't find right answer

i want to redirect

> subdomain.domain.com

to

> domain.com/directory/

i tried redirecting from cpanel but it only redirects subdomain.domain.com to domain.com very well but post links as

> subdomain.domain.com/post

or not redirecting to

> domain.com/directory/

I am using Litespeed web server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "_but posts links as_ .." yes the posts links won't redirect because cpanel only redirecting the domain. You need to have `.htaccess` rules or change your urls from database.

Comment: can you help me to do this via htaccess ?